how to calc the equivalent capacitance of this circuit
This is the input divider circuit of Zmod Scope Reference Manual,Can anyone explain what the following equivalent capacitance means,and how to calculate ?



[Edit]
The following condition must be met for a properly adjusted attenuator (see schematic below).
$${{1\over C1}\over {1 \over C2}}={C2/C1} = R1/R2$$
Thus
$$ C1 = {C2\;{R2\over R1}} = 390 \;pF \; {40200 \over 939980} = 16.679 \; pF$$
Substituting \$C1\$ in the equation for capacitors in series
$$ C_{in-parallel} = {1\over {1\over C1}+{1\over C2}} = {C2 \; R2 \over {R1+R2}} = 15.995\; pF  $$
This is the equation referred to in the manual.
Actual circuit capacitance values will be slightly different due to wiring & component capacitances plus the tolerances of the components which is why a variable capacitor is used for the final adjustment of the attenuator.
[Previous answer for a general case solution]
It is a loose approximation of the parallel input capacitance for their particular implementation of the circuit. The actual formula for the input capacitance is a rather cumbersome equation. A simpler way to find the parallel input capacitance is doing a SPICE simulation to see how good the equation is.

If you want to battle the algebra:

Find the admittance of the circuit.
Separate the real and imaginary portions of the admittance equation.
The imaginary part of the equation is the susceptance (\$B\$)
which is the reactive portion of the circuit.
Convert the susceptance to capacitance. \$C_{parallel} = B/\omega \$ where \$\omega\$ is the angular frequency.


The solution on the left uses the equation which was obtained using the techniques described above. \$C_p = 9.013 \; pF\$ at 10 Hz.
The solution on the right is the approximation given in your reference, about a 74% error. \$C_{papx} = 15.675 \; pF\$ at 10 Hz.
LTspice simulation gives \$C_p = 9.013221 \;pF\$ at 10 Hz.
Comparing the circuit solution with the LTspice simulation, the error is negligible.

One thing the schematic of the input circuitry don't show is the wiring capacitance which probably makes the approximation match reality which may be completely by chance. This is a polite way of saying the equation in the reference is bogus. By observation one would expect the parallel capacitance to be near 9.1 pF. Change C1 in the simulation to 20 pF and the referenced equation still says the capacitance is 15.675 pF when it should be closer to 20 pF.

one more question,i used LTspice to simulate the  circuit,but can not get the same result ,image

@armcc The equation in your screenshot is trying to calculate gain/omega. The equation in my simulation is calculating the parallel input capacitance of the network by taking the imaginary part of the admittance divided by omega (2pif). The equation used is $ -Im(I(V1)/V(in))/omega $ . The left-axis is set to Cartesian (right-click on the left-axis legend).

For scg_lg node,first simplify the parallel capacitance combination involving C4 with C2 or C5 ,take equivalent of capacitor with impedance (1/2pifc)then four impedance element connected to common  node(two resistance and two impedance)apply ratio metric relation between impedance and resistance elements.
